# update project fails in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Iam unable to clone/pull/push a repo from intellij where as I could do that in terminal using git clone/pull/push. Iam getting "unable to access   The requested URL returned error: 502" error. The issue is not with the repo as am able to clone it in terminal. I tried with and without proxy but same error. Any other settings do i need to change? I'm using latest intellij version

Comment: The description is a bit confusing. Is it cloning that fails, or Update the project? How the proxy is configured (in git config, somewhere else)?

Comment: can you clone it in the terminal without setting any proxy anywhere (`.gitconfig` file and system proxy settings)?